# HTTP POST + ANDROID not giving response

Tags: android

I am beginner for Android. I want to send the data to my PHP page. but here i m trying to toast that post values. but there is no response. Plz help me.
My Code is:

```
public class send_msgActivity extends Activity{

//static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.send_msg);

    Button btn_ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);

    btn_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sender);
            String S_name = editText1.getText().toString();
            EditText editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reciever);
            String S_email = editText2.getText().toString();
        postData(S_name,S_email);    
        }
    });
};

public void postData(String name,String email) {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.URL.com/yourpage.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Fname", name));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Femail", email));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        //HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost, new BasicResponseHandler());
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String reverseString = response.toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, "response" + reverseString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
} 
}
```

Comment: You never called your method. And you should only call it in an AsyncTask.

Comment: VM is right. The only thing you're doing right now is setting the texts of the edittext fields to a string. You still have to use the postData method. Until Android 2.3 you were able to just add this method in your on click listener but this is bad practise. Use AsyncTask instead. There are plenty of tutorials online for this.

Comment: Sry for my mistake. but i hv called that methods,and forget to written here. now my actual code is this.

Answer (score 0):

Use this example how to code `HTTPpost` method

```
package com.example.login;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;a
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;



import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class pdf extends Activity
{
    public boolean connect=false,logged=false;
    public String db_select;
    ListView l1;
    String mPwd,UName1="Success",UName,ret;
    public Iterator<String> itr;
    private String SERVICE_URL = "http://61.12.7.197:8080/Agero/person/pdf";
    private String SERVICE_URL1 = "http://61.12.7.197:8080/Agero/person/url";
    //private final String SERVICE_URL = "http://10.1.1.138:8080/Agero/person/pdf";
    //private final String SERVICE_URL1 = "http://10.1.1.138:8080/Agero/person/url";
    private final String TAG = "Course";
    ArrayList<String> todoItems;
    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
    ConnectionDetector cd;
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
    public List<String> list1=new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pdf);
         l1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
         todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
            aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_row,R.id.title,todoItems);
            l1.setAdapter(aa);
            todoItems.clear();
            cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
            isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
            if(isInternetPresent)
            {
            try
            {
                validat_user();
                //display("hi");

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                display("Network error.\nPlease check with your network settings.");
            }
            }
            else
            {
                display("No Internet Connection..");
            }

            l1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 String name=(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                 /*Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),Webview.class);
                  i.putExtra("USERNAME", name);
                  startActivity(i);*/
                 cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
                    isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
                 if(isInternetPresent)
                    {
                 try
                    {
                        validat_user1(name);

                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        display("Network error.\nPlease check with your network settings.");

                    }

                    }
                 else
                    {
                        display("No Internet Connection..");
                    }
                }
            });




    }
    public void display(String msg) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(pdf.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    private void validat_user()
    {

        WebServiceTask wst = new WebServiceTask(WebServiceTask.POST_TASK, this, "");

       // wst.addNameValuePair("State", stg1);
       // wst.addNameValuePair("Emp_PWD", stg2);
       // db_select=stg1;
        //display("I am");
        wst.execute(new String[] { SERVICE_URL });
        //display(SERVICE_URL);

    }
    private void validat_user1(String stg1)
    {
        db_select=stg1;
        WebServiceTask wst = new WebServiceTask(WebServiceTask.POST_TASK, this, "Loading...");

        wst.addNameValuePair1("PDF_NAME", stg1);


        wst.execute(new String[] { SERVICE_URL1 });

    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void no_net()
    {
        display( "No Network Connection");
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(pdf.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("No Internet Connection");
        alertDialog.setMessage("You don't have internet connection.\nElse please check the Internet Connection Settings.");
        //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.error_info);
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog.setButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {   
                alertDialog.cancel();
                pdf.this.finish();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setButton2("Use Local DataBase", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                display( "Accessing local DataBase.....");
                alertDialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    private class WebServiceTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        public static final int POST_TASK = 1;

        private static final String TAG = "WebServiceTask";

        // connection timeout, in milliseconds (waiting to connect)
        private static final int CONN_TIMEOUT = 3000;

        // socket timeout, in milliseconds (waiting for data)
        private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 5000;

        private int taskType = POST_TASK;
        private Context mContext = null;
        private String processMessage = "Processing...";

        private ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        private ProgressDialog pDlg = null;

        public WebServiceTask(int taskType, Context mContext, String processMessage) {

            this.taskType = taskType;
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.processMessage = processMessage;
        }

        public void addNameValuePair1(String name, String value) {

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        private void showProgressDialog() {

            pDlg = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            pDlg.setMessage(processMessage);
            pDlg.setProgressDrawable(mContext.getWallpaper());
            pDlg.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDlg.setCancelable(false);
            pDlg.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            showProgressDialog();

        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String url = urls[0];
            String result = "";

            HttpResponse response = doResponse(url);

            if (response == null) {
                return result;
            } else {

                try {

                    result = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());

                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
                }

            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

            handleResponse(response);
            pDlg.dismiss();

        }


        // Establish connection and socket (data retrieval) timeouts
        private HttpParams getHttpParams() {

            HttpParams htpp = new BasicHttpParams();

            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(htpp, CONN_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(htpp, SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

            return htpp;
        }

        private HttpResponse doResponse(String url) {

            // Use our connection and data timeouts as parameters for our
            // DefaultHttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(getHttpParams());

            HttpResponse response = null;

            try {
                switch (taskType) {

                case POST_TASK:
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                    // Add parameters
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                display("Remote DataBase can not be connected.\nPlease check network connection.");

                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
                return null;

            }

            return response;
        }

        private String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {

            String line = "";
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

            // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            try {
                // Read response until the end
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    total.append(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            }

            // Return full string
            return total.toString();
        }

    }
    public void handleResponse(String response) 
    {    //display("JSON responce is : "+response);
        if(!response.equals(""))
        {
       try {

            JSONObject jso = new JSONObject(response);


                  int UName = jso.getInt("status1");

                  if(UName==1)
                  {
                      String status = jso.getString("status");
                      ret=status.substring(13,status.length()-2);
                      todoItems.add(0, status);
                    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                  }
                  else if(UName==-1)
                  {
                      String status = jso.getString("status");
                      //display(status);
                        Intent intObj=new Intent(pdf.this,Webview.class);
                         intObj.putExtra("USERNAME", status);
                        startActivity(intObj);
                  }
                  else
                  {
//                     int count=Integer.parseInt(UName);
//                     display("Number of Projects have been handling in AFL right now: "+count);
                    list1=new ArrayList<String>();

                    JSONArray array=jso.getJSONArray("reps1");
                    for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
                    {
                        list1.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("pdfName"));

                    }
                    itr=list1.iterator();
                    while(itr.hasNext())
                    {
                         //str1=itr.next()+"\n";
                        todoItems.add(0, itr.next().toString());
                        aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    //tv1.setText(str1);


                  }      
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            return;
        }
        }
        else
        {
            display("unable to reach the server");
        }


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.home:
            Intent intObj=new Intent(pdf.this, MainActivity.class);
            intObj.putExtra("finish", true); // if you are checking for this in your other Activities
            intObj.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intObj);
            //pdf.this.finish();
            finish();
            return (true);

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```